# the asp.net core module is required to host asp.net core projects in iis express and does not appear to be installed. try repairing visual studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

When I am trying to install visual studio 2019....First it installed correctly but when I am trying to run then it shows that error : "the asp.net core module is required to host asp.net core projects in iis express and does not appear to be installed. try repairing visual studio" .
I have installed hosting bundle also and do many tricks which available on google but it is not debuging and not running on chrome. Shows error on this picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Mm3b.png)

Answer (score 4):

Which version of Asp.net Core version you are using? At present the latest version of Visual Studio will install the .NET Core 5 SDK and runtime. When you install the Visual Studio 2019, please make sure you have selected the relates Asp.net core components, check this screenshot:

[image]

Then, about the [ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-5.0), it is installed with the .NET Core Runtime from the .NET Core Hosting Bundle.

So, you could download the .NET Core Hosting Bundle via [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0)(based on the .NET Core version to select the related Hosting Bundle), and then install it:

[image]

Comment: I am using visual studio 2019....yes I have done all the steps already that you told but it always write when I click On IIS Exprees.the asp.net core module is required to host asp.net core projects in iis express and does not appear to be installed. try repairing visual studio

Comment: "I am using visual studio 2019....", from the .NET Core download page or the [Asp.net core document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), we can see that the .Net Core 5 version required VS 2019 16.8 or later version. So, try to install the latest version of VS 2019. After testing the above method, if still not working, try to create a new web application to check it. If the problem continues, try to install the VS 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio Installer -> Modify => check the box of "ASP.NET and web development" click on Modify button (at the right below corner).

[check the image below:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzqRr.png)